# How can I build "C" VlFeat library for Android

Tags: android, build, vlfeat

I would like to use the "C" VlFeat (http://www.vlfeat.org/index.html) library for Android.
Is there an official build?
Is there a simple way for building it?

Thanks,

Israel Sadeh

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds rude, but did you try searching via google? E.g. http://code.google.com/p/mcreader-indep/source/browse/

Comment: I did try googling the problem.
The only relevant result I found is the project McReader from http://code.google.com/p/mcreader-indep/ in which svereral 'heavily modified' VlFeat sources were compiled for Android.

Comment: I'm looking for a complete solution for building the whole 'stand-alone' VlFeat library that can be used in a simmilar way that the openCV C++ libraries are used.

Comment: Did you find how to do that?